# Why do car blinkers seem to synchronize and then diverse from each other?

Tags: automotive, time, lighting

When I am on the road, the blinkers of other cars seem to sync together for a few clicks and then they diverse again.

Is this just me seeing it wrong - so on fact they never sync - or is there some reason behind it's timing?

Comment: An analogy - if my clock runs fast by fifteen minutes every day, then in 96 days it will be correct again, having gained a day in the process, and will appear in sync with reality for a bit before diverging again. Nothing unexpected here.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with electronics. Two mechanical metronomes set to slightly different tempos will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @TannerSwett, I imagine you mean "this is not unique to electronics", rather than "this doesn't really have anything to do with electronics" which it very clearly does.

Comment: `Why do car blinkers seem to synchronize` ... because they happen to turn on at nearly the same time every once in a while .... think about planetary orbits and planetary conjunctions .... seems like you didn't think much before posting your question

Comment: You're not the only one who is maybe (slightly) obsessed with this ;-) surprisingly, someone made a video about this, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2z5A-COlDPk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Beating of two frequencies. (Illustration by Transistor.)*

Any two systems operating at differing frequencies will "beat" at the difference between the two frequencies. So if one turn signal / indicator / blinker is running at 60 flashes per minute and another at 62 then they will come into phase twice per minute.

Links:

- [Beat (acoustics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)).

Answer (score 2):

You should see the "beat frequency" between the two flasher rates. I suspect modern cars, especially from the same maker, might have rates that are almost exactly the same (crystal controlled).

The rate is apparently specified in (paid standard) SAE J590 (60 - 120 flashes per minute, with 90 being the ideal).

Answer (score -1):

It's not you, it is a real thing.

While there probably is a specified frequency range for turn signals, there is no one standard frequency.  In most cars today the freq is determined by one of the many microprocessors running the vehicle.

Back when the flasher was an electro-mechanical device that used a bi-metallic strip that bent when heated by the current going through it.  You can see the effect of this in a car with a very rapid turn signal freq.  It means that one of the bulbs has burned out.